# Visual Studio 2013 intellisense in web forms editor only shows one option - the "db" attribute

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

This has been driving me nuts for ages. I've tried to live with it, but I enjoy the autocomplete helping-hand of intellisense too much.

It seems that whenever a web forms control (e.g. Repeater) is inside a html control (e.g. p or div) which is itself inside a web forms control (e.g. Panel) that my intellisense decides the only attribute I could ever want or need is "db" (the tooltip description is "Markup snippet for a data-bind attribute").

For example, this would produce the error (can't include img as I've only just signed up for an account):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ...
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

[image]

Compared to this, which would work fine:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Has anyone else come across this issue? Could I perhaps be missing some kind of intellisense option/setting? Or is this more likely something I should bring up with Microsoft itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came across this. I stumbled across a solution which worked for me by clicking on the Toolbox menu where you would normally go to drag and drop controls onto the designer. When I did that, Visual Studio seemed to load some extensions which had the effect of restoring my intellisense. I hope that works for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 3 years later.. xD

All you need to do is: Set a target framework in your web.config:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#">
  <assemblies>
    ...
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try checking your web.config.

In my case, there was a 'runtime' tag asking for some dll's I didnt have in the project references.

Hope it helps.

Comment: could you please answer the question complete with necessary description?